# Visual Studio natvis file: map iterator operator * overloading

Tags: c++, visual-studio, natvis

I have in a project a custom made map class/container which includes an iterator. The iterator has (*) operator defined to return the key of the pointed map element. I use a natvis file to show the custom map in the way I want and also the iterator and it works. Problem is when I put in the watch window something like:

```
*fooIterator
```

I get:

```
no operator "*" matches these operands
```

What to do in the natvis file to overcome this?

Comment: Can you provide code and natvis that show the problem?